# Wordpress plugin with Composer auto update when enabling

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php

We are developing a custom WordPress plugin. We also require within plugin some composer packages. When enabling the plugin we must run through terminal "composer update".

Is there any option to autorun to download packages needed?

Comment: Why would you run `composer` on enable? The plugin should include all of the libraries and packages to run - including any vendor added scripts. If this is hosted on the WP plugin repository, when you make an update to push to users, then the updated libraries would be included. Is there something your plugin does that requires composer to update the vendor packages? Will this be for the public?

Comment: This is a private plugin and is not hosted on WP plugin repository. I don't understand why should we commit composer vendor modules. Similar to this when using npm for example package manager you never commit node_modules.